# Who first proved Peano Arithmetic is not finitely axiomatizable?

Tags: logic, math-history, peano-axioms

By Peano Arithmetic I mean first order Peano Arithmetic.  The earliest proof that it is not finitely axiomatizable that I know of is R. Montague, Semantical Closure and Non-Finite Axiomatizability I. J. Symbolic Logic 29 (1964), no. 1, 59--60.  But was the result known by other means before that?

Answer (score 12):

In 1952 Czesław Ryll-Nardzewski proved that first order PA is not finitely axiomatizable. The proof uses nonstandard models. Andrzej Mostowski proved the same result (also in 1952) but without using nonstandard models.

Comment: The Mostowski reference is:  Andrzej Mostowski, 1952, "Models of axiomatic systems", *Fundamenta Mathematicae*  39:1, 133-158. See sec 7 of http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm39/fm39112.pdf . Mostowski simply demonstrated the now-standard fact that PA proves the consistency of each of its finite subtheories.

Answer (score 9):

[Czesław Ryll-Nardzewski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Czes%C5%82aw_Ryll-Nardzewski), The Role of the Axiom of Induction in the Elementary Arithmetic, *Fundamenta Mathematicae* 39 (1952).

Comment: Thanks.  This paper manipulates non-standard models to show every sentence of PA (and thus every finite conjunction of axioms) has a model where some instance of the induction axiom scheme fails.